# Using the javascript code along with the html code

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JavaScript. I have the following piece of code in my HTML page, but it  doesn't give the expected output.

```
<body>
    <script>
    var a=1;
    if(a==2)
    </script>
    <h3>this is h3 heading.</h3>
</body>
```

The output is `this is h3 heading`, but I think the condition fails and hence it doesn't produce any result. How would I get this to run?
  Can anyone tell me,how the above  javascript code  and html works.
  My exact doubt is,when a html page consists of the html tags and javascript code,Who and how those html tags and js code is executed?

Comment: There is nothing to execute after the test `(a==2)`. What is the expected result of your code?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: your script is failing, throwing an error that is logged on browser console. hence the rendering breaks and javascript has no way of compiling it. Hence the runtime error. Please let us know what you are expecting

Comment: Why would people downvote this question. Yes. Maybe its poorly formatted and the OP is obviously new to JavaScript. Shouldn't we amend his mistake instead of lashing out at him.

Comment: @Neurofluxation No. It literally was not a question until you edited it. We can't know if that edit reflects the OP's actual question. If there's no question, logically there can be no answer.

Comment: @AlexW - without arguing, it's not hard to deduce what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @AlexW, you have to understand that English is not the native language for many SO users and we need to work around that issue. Anyways, its like Neouro said, its not hard to deduce what the OP wanted.

Comment: @MarsOne - *neuro*, but I'll let you off ;)

Comment: @MarsOne I could edit the post and "deduce" that he wanted it to *not run* that doesn't mean I am correct..or maybe he wants it to run on phone browsers, but not desktops. We don't know. That's why the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says be specific. By the way, there were 4 downvotes before neuro's edit and I was not one of them.

Comment: @AlexW, people nowadays downvote for zero reason, Personally downvoting someone with 1 rep doesnt make any sense to me. If the question is bad, it should be flagged and the OP educate about it. My 2 cents :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Javascript - here's your code!

```
<body>
    <h3 id="header"></h3>
    <script>
    var a = 1; //set a to 1
    if (a == 2) { //if a is 2 then...
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "This is h3 Heading!"; //output
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Here's a JSFiddle with extended code including a function and click event. Simply click on the "Result" area to increment `a` by 1 and get a result!!
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/8Lkax/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use such a condition you should either consider using PHP or you have to adjust the code, a possible solution would be the following:

```
       <BODY>
             <div id="test">

             </div>
                <script>
                 var a=1;
                 if(a==2)
                 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="<h3>this is h3 heading</h3>";
                </script>
                 </BODY>
```

by this you edit the innerHTML, that means the content, of the tag with the id test, if the condition in the script returns true. You could also solve it with PHP, but since you said that you are new to HTML you should probably try the JS solution first.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that JavaScript works in a completely different way to pre-processors like PHP.  The most important thing to understand here is that every `<script>` block runs separately, and has no effect on HTML around it.

So, when you write JavaScript and HTML mixed together (like in your example), it will do these things in order:

1. Set up an empty page (`<body>`)
2. Run the JavaScript inside the `<script>`
3. Add the `<h3>` to the page (including all the text)

There is *nothing* that the JavaScript can do in step #2 that will change step #3 at all.  The steps are all completely independent.  It doesn't matter whether your `if` statement succeeds or fails - step #3 will happen either way.

#### So what should you do instead?

A good pattern to start with (I think) is to put all your JavaScript at the bottom of the page.  This way, there are only two steps:

1. Load the page
2. Run the JavaScript

Once the page has loaded in step #1, the JavaScript can *alter* the page in step #2.  For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Today is a <span id="mood-result">???</span> day.

        <script>
            var resultElement = document.getElementById('mood-result');
            var a = 1;
            if (a === 2) {
                resultElement.innerHTML = "bad";
            } else {
                resultElement.innerHTML = "good";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what happens here is that the whole page loads (saying "Today is a ??? day"), and then the JavaScript immediately plucks an element out of the page, and changes it.

I think StackOverflow is not a great place to try and learn a language from scratch.  However, hopefully this will put you in a good place to understand another guide.  Have you tried [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)?